# java nio negate a glob pattern

Tags: java, nio, glob

```
fileSystem.getPathMatcher("glob:${pattern}").matches(path.getFileName())}
```

I want to match everything that DOES NOT match "ts.*". What's the syntax for that for a glob in java? (Before anyone suggests I use regex instead, I am required to use a glob)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we look at the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPathMatcher-java.lang.String-) we find that the only way how to negate something is by using bracket expressions.

> If the character after the [ is a ! then it is used for negation so [!a-c] matches any character except "a", "b", or "c".

So in your case the pattern could be something like `{[!t]*,t[!s]*,ts[!.]*}`.

A pattern like `[!t][!s][!.]*` would not work, because it would also not match files beginning with, e.g., `as.`.

Comment: This works. Thanks for making sense of a very confusing syntax.