# How to negate an inner character in a glob pattern

Tags: java, regex, string

The question
[java nio negate a glob pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48916176/java-nio-negate-a-glob-pattern)
asked how to make a glob pattern matching strings that do not start with a given character, say "a". The accepted answer

```
"[!a]*"
```

does work for starting characters and also for ending characters,

```
"*[!a]"
```

However, it does not work for positions in between. For example

```
"*[!.]*"
```

does not filter out file names with a dot somewhere inside the file name. (While, of course,

```
"*.*"
```

does filter out file names without a dot.) How can I do inner character negation?

Comment: Is this actually a glob pattern or regex?

Comment: glob. my question is answered below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works perfectly fine in the middle of matcher. The thing to realize is that `foo.bar` DOES match `*[!.]*`

To show that this is a match:

1. Let the first star match `foo.b`. This is allowed since it can match any string of any length.
2. The next character is not a period, so `[!.]` matches `a`
3. Let the second star match the remainder, `r`

This is the complete input, and therefore `foo.bar` matches `*[!.]*`.

The pattern matches "any string that contains a character that is not a period". You instead wanted "any string that does not contain any periods anywhere".

In regex, this is the difference between `^.*[^.].*$` and `^([^.])*$`.

Unfortunately, globs are not powerful enough to express what you want.

Comment: You don't need the `()` in the last regex. --- And maybe it should be a `+`, not a `*`, so empty string doesn't check as being ok. None of the other globs/patterns allowed empty string.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense.